# NGINX 499 error code after 60 seconds while downloading large files

Tags: java, nginx, timeout

I am facing this issue, wherein whenever i try to download a report(pdf/csv) file from my web application it timeouts after around 60 seconds. Below is the architecture.

WEB DOMAIN --> WEB NGINX -- > ANGULAR FRONTEND --> API NGINX --> JAVA API.

So once i remove the API side nginx . Reports download is working fine but i need it fot websocket configuration hence cannot remove it.

I have tried adding proxy timeout but it does not work. Please suggest what could be done.

I Have tried changing ALB timeout and added porxy timeouts.

## Below is my Nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;

#   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
#   include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
}
```

Below is VM cong:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
server {

    listen 80;
        server_name _;

        location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_connect_timeout       600;
         proxy_send_timeout          600;
         proxy_read_timeout          600;
         send_timeout                600;
         proxy_ignore_client_abort   on;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
         proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
        location /afcsIndore-stomp/  {
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}    
}
```

Comment: Your code managing the download probably has set a timeout of 60 sec causing the NGINX error.

Comment: I have tried removing nginx from API side and it worked fine.

Comment: are you using AWS? I assume you're not uploading to afcsIndore-stomp ?